# Node js unable to connect using http://127.0.0.1:3000

Tags: node.js

Hi I am very new to Node JS and I am trying to learn through Sams teach yourself in 24 hours. I have installed express globally and was following exactly book says.Installed express globally.

```
express jade_conditions
```

installed dependencies

```
cd jade_conditions && npm install
```

and ran

```
node app.js
```

and then asked to open browser with node http://127.0.0.1:3000/
and here is the problem because I am not able to open any site. It says Unable to connect. Am I missing anything. Because I dont understand where is this http://127.0.0.1:3000/ coming from. Can anyone help me how to see those jade.index file from the view folder on the browser ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `netstat -a | grep LISTEN | grep tcp`  to see if anything is listening for connections on port 3000

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to `app.listen(3000)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you creates an  app with `express-generator` then it won't be work with `node app.js` since listen configuration has been done in `bin/www` folder and it will run with `start command`

Do this

```
> npm start
```

And open your above link on broswer

And if you want to use `node app.js` then listen it on a particular port in  your app.js file like this

```
> app.listen(3000);
```

And use `node app.js` and it will work

For reference check it in details here: https://github.com/expressjs/express#quick-start

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm start` instead of `node app.js`. Mentioned here: https://github.com/expressjs/express#quick-start

That will actually run `node bin/www` instead of `app.js`, which sets the port to 3000 before starting the server.